# System level git config in mac

Tags: macos, git

I am able to see global and local config files at usual locations.

But if i type

```
git config --system --list
```

it gives me

```
fatal: unable to read config file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc/gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

- Any idea why it is looking there?
- And why it is not set?  Where is
- system git config location for Mac?

There is no file at `/etc/gitconfig` or `$HOME/.config/git` (prescribed location got *nix and osx respectively)

> EDIT

doing

```
sudo git config --system --list
```

does not help

Answer (score 3):

@Abhijit Mazumder:

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar issue when attempting to set a system level git config value on my mac and thought I would post my solution here in case it could help you.

> NOTE: I strongly suspect that if you simply create the
>   '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/etc/' directory and create a
>   file called gitconfig within that directory, then your attempts at
>   viewing or setting system level git config values will be successful.

My first attempt at setting a system level git config value on my mac was:

```
git config --system alias.cl clone
```

This resulted in an error:

```
error: could not lock config file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/etc/gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

I thought perhaps I needed to add 'sudo' to the command:

```
sudo git config --system alias.cl clone
```

But running the command with 'sudo' gave me the same error:

```
error: could not lock config file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/etc/gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

So, from the root directory on my mac, I switched into the 'usr' directory mentioned in the error, just to see what was in there:

```
cd Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/
```

I was surprised to find that there was no 'etc' directory. The only directories I saw were 'bin', 'lib', 'libexec', and 'share'.

So I decided to create what was missing. I first created an 'etc' directory:

```
sudo mkdir etc
```

And then created a gitconfig file in the 'etc' directory:

```
sudo touch etc/gitconfig
```

I was then able to set a system level git config value with the following command:

```
sudo git config --system alias.cl clone
```

In order to confirm that the system level git config value had actually been set, I viewed the contents of the gitconfig file.

I first used the unix 'cat' command while inside my 'usr' directory:

```
cat etc/gitconfig
```

The output from the 'cat' command was:

```
[alias]
    cl = clone
```

Then I used a git command (the same one you were trying to use in your question) to check that my system level git config value had been set:

```
git config --system --list
```

The output from this command was:

```
alias.cl=clone
```

The last thing I needed to do to ensure that I had placed my file in the proper location was try the alias I had created, so I tried running:

```
git cl
```

Running this command using the alias I created resulted in the following output, which confirmed for me that everything was working properly:

```
You must specify a repository to clone.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --progress            force progress reporting
    -n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
    --bare                create a bare repository
    --mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)
    -l, --local           to clone from a local repository
    --no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
    -s, --shared          setup as shared repository
    --recursive           initialize submodules in the clone
    --recurse-submodules  initialize submodules in the clone
    --template <template-directory>
                          directory from which templates will be used
    --reference <repo>    reference repository
    --dissociate          use --reference only while cloning
    -o, --origin <name>   use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
    -b, --branch <branch>
                          checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
    -u, --upload-pack <path>
                          path to git-upload-pack on the remote
    --depth <depth>       create a shallow clone of that depth
    --single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
    --separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                          separate git dir from working tree
    -c, --config <key=value>
                          set config inside the new repository
```

Comment: Nice work around but why was it not present by default ? According to https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup , It should contain values for every user on the system and all their repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I have not come across this error as my machines are only used by me so setting `--global` level is enough, however that location looks reasonable (I assume you are using the `git` supplied with the Xcode command line tools).

Using `sudo` to configure what you want should work:

```
$ sudo git config --system <name> <value>
```

Comment: What configuration setting did you try to set? If you're just using `--system --list` but have never set any config options, you will get the "unable to read file" error. The first time you set system-level configuration, the file will be created.

Comment: hi as per my understanding system level file should be created by git itself just the way global config gets created. I did nit set up global config explicitly

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder Can you tell me exactly what you typed (the example command line I give is only an example; what did you substitute for `<name>` and `<value>`?).

Comment: `sudo git config --system --list`

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder Set something first before using `--list`.